# Error en IntelliJ IDEA con maven

Tags: java, sql, maven, intellij-idea

El error me sale justo después de que el usuario introduzca el nombre del usuario

La base de datos esta relacionada asi:

[image: Los nombres subrayados son los nombres de las tablas]

Errores tras quitar `<type>pom</type>`

```
Se ha producido un error en la conexión con la base de datos
java.sql.SQLDataException: Current position is after the last row
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.SelectResultSet.checkObjectRange(SelectResultSet.java:628)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.SelectResultSet.getInt(SelectResultSet.java:1000)
    at chat.Controller.getAutogenerated(Controller.java:182)
    at chat.Controller.createAlumno(Controller.java:55)
    at chat.View.showLoginMenu(View.java:38)
    at chat.View.show(View.java:25)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Crear Alumno:**

```
    public int createAlumno(String name) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Alumno VALUE (?, ?)");
        stmt.setInt(1, this.getAutogenerated(stmt));
        stmt.setString(2, name);
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
        return this.getAutogenerated(stmt);
    }
```

**Generar Clave:**

```
    private int getAutogenerated (Statement stmt) throws SQLException {
        ResultSet keys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        keys.next();
        return keys.getInt(1);
    }
```

Comment: Hola @Paull, el tipo de error que tienes se suele producir cuando realizas la conexión de la base datos, lo que te esta diciendo `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver` es que no tiene dentro de tus dependencias el jar con el Driver de MariaDB, por favor coloca el código de la conexión y el POM.

Comment: Lo acabo de añadir

Comment: Recuerdo que `<type>pom</type>` se utiliza únicamente en la sección de `dependencyManagement`, pero para importar una librería no es necesario, quita esa parte y refresca las dependencias.

Comment: Nada, me siguen saliendo error, actualizo ahora

Comment: Si es verdad, pero el error del driver esta solucionado quitando `<type>pom</type>` que era tu principal problema, este nuevo error es debido a la forma en la que programas la acción de la base de datos, aunque no es el error inicial agrega las forma en que realizas la consulta a la base de datos y el método getAutogenerated.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón ese primer error se solucionó, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hummmm, con este nuevo código tienes varios errores, intentare listarlos y explicarlos en una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

según los errores que he revisado, tendrías las siguientes soluciones:

Error 1: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`

Esto se debe a que utilizabas `<type>pom</type>` en la dependencia:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <type>pom</type> 
</dependency>
```

Solución: eliminar `<type>pom</type>` para que se importe correctamente la libreria.

Error 2: java.sql.SQLDataException: Current position is after the last row

En este error lo que sucede es que estas utilizando incorrectamente `getGeneratedKeys()`,
este método del `PreparedStatement` sirve para obtener la `llave primaria` cuando es autogenerada por la base de datos, pero según tu lógica esperas que el `PreparedStatement` la genere en el metodo `this.getAutogenerated(stmt)`.

Lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:
Primero verifica que efectivamente en tu base de datos el `ID` sea autoincrementado, prueba insertar manualmente un dato sin especificar el `ID` si la base lo agrega entonces debería de funcionar el siguiente código.

```
public int createAlumno(String name) throws SQLException {

        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Alumno (nombre) VALUE (?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.setString(1, name);

        int filasInsertadas = stmt.executeUpdate();

        if (filasInsertadas == 0) {
            throw new SQLException("error, no se insertaron datos");
        }

        int id = getAutogenerated(stmt);

        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

        return id;
    }

private int getAutogenerated (Statement stmt) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet generatedKeys  = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
    if (generatedKeys.next()) {
       return generatedKeys.getInt(1);
    }else {
        throw new SQLException("Error al obtener el ID para Alumno.");
    }
}
```

Cambios:

Modificamos el `INSERT` para insertar únicamente el nombre y que la base datos agregue el `ID`.

Para obtener el `ID` debemos solicitarlo agregando `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` cuando se crea el `PreparedStatement`.

Un punto importante es que no ejecutas el `PreparedStatement` por lo tanto nuca se insertarían los datos esto lo solucionamos de la siguiente forma `int filasInsertadas = stmt.executeUpdate();` la ejecución retorna la cantidad de filas insertadas o modificadas en caso de un `UPDATE`.

Por ultimo después de ejecutar el `INSERT` y antes de cerrar la conexión ejecutamos el método para obtener el `ID`.

Estas modificaciones tiene mucho margen de mejora, por lo que te recomiendo un tutorial en video o que busque algún otro material para que veas las mejores formas de majear las conexiones y la ejecución de consultas SQL con JDBC.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zh3_Gn_eXhM&ab_channel=Gesti%C3%B3nRt24

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!!!!!!! Y gracias también por el video no lo conocía